# R data.table - remove rows corresponding to a given marginal

Tags: r, data.table, delete-row

I have the following problem. I have a data.table and a subset of columns `M`. I have vector `x` defined on `M`.

```
library(data.table)
data <- matrix(c(0,0,NA,1,0,1,NA,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,NA,NA,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,NA,0,1,1,0,1,1,1), byrow = T, ncol = 6, dimnames = LETTERS[1:6])
dt <- data.table(data)
dt
%     A B  C  D  E F
% 1:  0 0 NA  1  0 1
% 2: NA 1  0  0  1 0
% 3:  1 1 NA NA  1 0
% 4:  0 1  0  0  1 1
% 5:  1 0  0  1 NA 0
% 6:  1 1  0  1  1 1

M = LETTERS[2:5]
x <- dt[2,..M]
x
%    B C D E
% 1: 1 0 0 1
```

I would like to remove all rows from `dt` with marginal on `M` equal to `x`. I.e. rows no. 2 and 4. Both `M` and `x` change during the program. The result for the given `M` and `x` will be:

```
   A B  C  D  E F
1: 0 0 NA  1  0 1
2: 1 1 NA NA  1 0
3: 1 0  0  1 NA 0
4: 1 1  0  1  1 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

data.table anti-join

```
dt[!x, on = M] # also works: dt[!dt[2], on = M]

#    A B  C  D  E F
# 1: 0 0 NA  1  0 1
# 2: 1 1 NA NA  1 0
# 3: 1 0  0  1 NA 0
# 4: 1 1  0  1  1 1
```

Base R

```
eq2 <- Reduce('&', lapply(dt[, ..M], function(x) x == x[2]))

dt[-which(eq2),]
#    A B  C  D  E F
# 1: 0 0 NA  1  0 1
# 2: 1 1 NA NA  1 0
# 3: 1 0  0  1 NA 0
# 4: 1 1  0  1  1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a `data.table` option, but with `base R` you can do:

```
data[rowSums(sweep(data[, M], 2, FUN = `==`, x), na.rm = TRUE) != length(x), ]

     A B  C  D  E F
[1,] 0 0 NA  1  0 1
[2,] 1 1 NA NA  1 0
[3,] 1 0  0  1 NA 0
[4,] 1 1  0  1  1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution

```
> subset(dt,!data.frame(t(dt[,..M])) %in% data.frame(t(x)))
   A B  C  D  E F
1: 0 0 NA  1  0 1
2: 1 1 NA NA  1 0
3: 1 0  0  1 NA 0
4: 1 1  0  1  1 1
```